# public static const in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there such a thing as public static constants in TypeScript?  I have a class that looks like:

```
export class Library {
  public static BOOK_SHELF_NONE: string = "None";
  public static BOOK_SHELF_FULL: string = "Full";
}
```

In that class, I can do `Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE` and the tsc doesn't complain.  But if I try to use the class Library elsewhere, and try to do the same thing, it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Can you show an example of using that class elsewhere?

Comment: @raina77ow As I started adding in the code for how I use it, I realized that it's because of namespacing that the tsc complained.  If you want to put that in as an answer I can mark it as complete since you helped me find it.  I don't really like answering my own questions.

Comment: Ah, that was the cause. ) Glad I helped; I'll add the answer showing the results of compilation.

Comment: I'd also add [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier) to make sure TypeScript will warn you if you ever tried to reassign those fields: `public static readonly BOOK_SHELF_FULL`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's what's this TS snippet compiled into (via [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground)):

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var Library = (function () {
        function Library() {
        }
        Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE = "None";
        Library.BOOK_SHELF_FULL = "Full";
        return Library;
    })();
    exports.Library = Library;
});
```

As you see, both properties defined as `public static` are simply attached to the exported function (as its properties); therefore they should be accessible as long as you properly access the function itself.

Answer (score 508):

If you did want something that behaved more like a static constant value in modern browsers (in that it can't be changed by other code), you could add a `get` only accessor to the `Library` class (this will only work for ES5+ browsers and NodeJS):

```
export class Library {
    public static get BOOK_SHELF_NONE():string { return "None"; }
    public static get BOOK_SHELF_FULL():string { return "Full"; }   
}

var x = Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE;
console.log(x);
Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE = "Not Full";
x = Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE;
console.log(x);
```

If you run it, you'll see how the attempt to set the `BOOK_SHELF_NONE` property to a new value doesn't work.

### 2.0

In TypeScript 2.0, you can use `readonly` to achieve very similar results:

```
export class Library {
    public static readonly BOOK_SHELF_NONE = "None";
    public static readonly BOOK_SHELF_FULL = "Full";
}
```

The syntax is a bit simpler and more obvious. However, the compiler prevents changes rather than the run time (unlike in the first example, where the change would not be allowed at all as demonstrated).

Comment: This solution has a drawback though - you cannot use these *dynamic* values as type constraint, for instance:
`type MyType: Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE | Library.BOOK_SHELF_FULL;`

Comment: Let's say I have mutliple constants classes and I want all my constants classes to contain a specific method to check if a arbitrary constant is defined inside the class. I tried: `class Constants {
    isDefined(id) {if ... return boolean;}}` and `class UiConstants extends Constants { public static get ARTICLE():string { return 'ARTICLE'; } }`. If I use `UiConstants` without new `UiConstants.ARTICLE` is defined but `UiConstants.isDefined()` remains undefined. If I instantiate `new UiConstants` then `UiConstants.isDefined()` method is defined but `UiConstants.ARTICLE` vanishes.

Comment: I have found the answer to this issue. I had removed the `static` keyword in order to use instances of the `uiConstants`. This way I have both the constants and the `isDefined()` method. This suits me well in my usecase.

Comment: For TypeScript 2.0 and angularjs 1.5, do we add the constant class as a service? what is the best practice to do it?

Comment: What about enums ?

Comment: I think we only needs `static readonly BOOK_SHELF_NONE = "None";`. Right? The `public` can be removed and works just the same.

Answer (score 57):

You can do it using [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), like this:

```
export namespace Library {
    export const BOOK_SHELF_NONE: string = 'NONE';
}
```

Then you can import it from anywhere else:

```
import {Library} from './Library';
console.log(Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE);
```

If you need a class there as well include it inside the namespace: `export class Book {...}`

Comment: If i'm using the constants in the initialization of an object, they don't seem to be recognized. For example: `{ type: Library.BOOK_SHELF_NONE }` seems to think that the namespace has no export called `BOOK_SHELF_NONE`. However, if I just set a local variable with the reference, it resolves it fine. TS 2.2

Answer (score 13):

Meanwhile this can be solved through a decorator in combination with `Object.freeze` or `Object.defineProperty`, I'm using this, it's a little bit prettier than using tons of getters. You can copy/paste this directly [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) to see it in action. - There are two options

---

#### Make individual fields "final"

The following decorator converts both, annotated static and non-static fields to "getter-only-properties".

**Note**: If an instance-variable with no initial value is annotated `@final`, then the first assigned value (no matter when) will be the final one.

```ts
// example
class MyClass {
    @final
    public finalProp: string = "You shall not change me!";

    @final
    public static FINAL_FIELD: number = 75;

    public static NON_FINAL: string = "I am not final."
}

var myInstance: MyClass = new MyClass();
myInstance.finalProp = "Was I changed?";
MyClass.FINAL_FIELD = 123;
MyClass.NON_FINAL = "I was changed.";

console.log(myInstance.finalProp);  // => You shall not change me!
console.log(MyClass.FINAL_FIELD);   // => 75
console.log(MyClass.NON_FINAL);     // => I was changed.
```

**The Decorator: Make sure you include this in your code!**

```
/**
* Turns static and non-static fields into getter-only, and therefor renders them "final".
* To use simply annotate the static or non-static field with: @final
*/
function final(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    const value: any = target[propertyKey];
    // if it currently has no value, then wait for the first setter-call
    // usually the case with non-static fields
    if (!value) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            set: function (value: any) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, propertyKey, {
                    get: function () {
                        return value;
                    },
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: false
                });
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    } else { // else, set it immediatly
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get: function () {
                return value;
            },
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
}
```

---

As an alternative to the decorator above, there would also be a strict version of this, which would even throw an Error when someone tried to assign some value to the field with `"use strict";` being set. (This is only the static part though)

```ts
/**
 * Turns static fields into getter-only, and therefor renders them "final".
 * Also throws an error in strict mode if the value is tried to be touched.
 * To use simply annotate the static field with: @strictFinal
 */
function strictFinal(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
        value: target[propertyKey],
        writable: false,
        enumerable: true
    });
}
```

---

#### Make every static field "final"

Possible Downside: This will only work for ALL statics of that class or for none, but cannot be applied to specific statics.

```ts
/**
* Freezes the annotated class, making every static 'final'.
* Usage:
* @StaticsFinal
* class MyClass {
*      public static SOME_STATIC: string = "SOME_STATIC";
*      //...
* }
*/
function StaticsFinal(target: any) {
    Object.freeze(target);
}
```

```ts
// Usage here
@StaticsFinal
class FreezeMe {
    public static FROZEN_STATIC: string = "I am frozen";
}

class EditMyStuff {
    public static NON_FROZEN_STATIC: string = "I am frozen";
}

// Test here
FreezeMe.FROZEN_STATIC = "I am not frozen.";
EditMyStuff.NON_FROZEN_STATIC = "I am not frozen.";

console.log(FreezeMe.FROZEN_STATIC); // => "I am frozen."
console.log(EditMyStuff.NON_FROZEN_STATIC); // => "I am not frozen."
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest approach. Thanks!

Comment: One small addition: `if (!value)` should be `if (value === undefined)` to let static values be `""` or `0`.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you WiredPrairie!

Just to expand on your answer a bit, here is a complete example of defining a constants class.

```
// CYConstants.ts

class CYConstants {
    public static get NOT_FOUND(): number    { return -1; }
    public static get EMPTY_STRING(): string { return ""; }
}

export = CYConstants;
```

To use

```
// main.ts

import CYConstants = require("./CYConstants");

console.log(CYConstants.NOT_FOUND);    // Prints -1
console.log(CYConstants.EMPTY_STRING); // Prints "" (Nothing!)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution also works as of TS 1.7.5.

```
// Constancts.ts    
export const kNotFoundInArray = -1;
export const AppConnectionError = new Error("The application was unable to connect!");
export const ReallySafeExtensions = ["exe", "virus", "1337h4x"];
```

To use:

```
// Main.ts    
import {ReallySafeExtensions, kNotFoundInArray} from "./Constants";

if (ReallySafeExtensions.indexOf("png") === kNotFoundInArray) {
    console.log("PNG's are really unsafe!!!");
}
```

Comment: This is really cool, but if you are using it to define more than a couple values (like you might in an Enum in other languages), then you are stuck importing all of the values individually. This could get cumbersome really quick!

Comment: 100% agreed. Might be able to namespace them but i haven't looked into it. Maybe you could import {ArrayConstants} from "./Constants.ts" and then do something like ArrayConstants.NotFound. Have to play with it more when i get time.

Comment: Yeah, you can use namespaces to avoid using values individually, read my own answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a getter, so that your property is going to be reading only.
Example:

```
export class MyClass {
    private _LEVELS = {
        level1: "level1",
        level2: "level2",
        level2: "level2"
    };

    public get STATUSES() {
        return this._LEVELS;
    }
}
```

Used in another class:

```
import { MyClass } from "myclasspath";
class AnotherClass {
    private myClass = new MyClass();

    tryLevel() {
       console.log(this.myClass.STATUSES.level1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes what is expected to be a constant writable: `let a = new MyClass(); a.STATUSES.level1 = 'not level1'; let plainWrong = new MyClass().STATUSES.level1; // 'not level1'`

Comment: Well... it's not a final constant and even if the member is private, you can completely access the object _LEVELS.
I just tried: 

this.myClass.STATUSES.level1 = 'blabla';

And it worked! You make the pointer itself private and clone it into a getter which points to the same, making it public

Answer (score 0):

Just simply 'export' variable and 'import' in your class

```
export var GOOGLE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1';

// default err string message
export var errStringMsg = 'Something went wrong';
```

Now use it as,

```
import appConstants = require('../core/AppSettings');
console.log(appConstants.errStringMsg);
console.log(appConstants.GOOGLE_API_URL);
```