# const on Angular2 with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Why when trying to declare a const I get error:

`Expecting new line or semicolon`

```
export class MyClass{

    const ALLOC_INVESTORS = "Allocation Investors";

}
```

Comment: If you [try it on the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20MyClass%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20const%20ALLOC_INVESTORS%20%3D%20%22Allocation%20Investors%22%3B%0A%0A%7D) it will tell you that `const` cannot be used in a class declaration.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan what would be the alternative for const inside a typescript class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37265275/215552 :)

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone needs.
instead of const, use readonly.

```
readonly ALLOC_INVESTORS:string = "Allocation Investors";
```