# A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using ts and keep getting stuck when trying to create const that can be used by just changing a simple element.keep getting A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword

code:

```
const LINKS = {
  Summary: 82,
  Telephone: 83
};

itemLocator(ItemId): Locator {
  const navItemSelector = `'div[id="${ItemId}"]'`
  return page.locator(itemLocator)
}
```

tired doing const function, and const

Comment: Right. A class member cannot have the `const` keyword. What's your question?

Comment: You can use readonly modifier instead. Look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265275/how-to-implement-class-constants

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement class constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265275/how-to-implement-class-constants)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mLlRZm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 2):

The [duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265275/how-to-implement-class-constants) that suggest using `readonly` in the comments are valid for simple properties.

In your case, because you're using an object property, you need an additional [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
class Test {
  readonly LINKS = {
    Summary: 82,
    Telephone: 83
  } as const;
}

const test = new Test();
test.LINKS = {}; // error
test.LINKS.Summary = 83; // error
```

Without the `const` assertion, you would still be able to change the value `Summary` and `Telephone` values inside `LINKS`.