# Confusing Functions with Classes in react.js

Tags: reactjs, function, class, syntax

Can you tell what’s wrong with the following code (my eyes are broken)?

```
class Numbers extends React.Component {
  const arrayOfNumbers = _.range(1, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I put your code in there https://www.typescriptlang.org
And it says *A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.*

I think that the issue with your code is that you try to make a class member constant by adding the `const` keyword.

But [a class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265275/how-to-implement-class-constants) (link found with [this amazing tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+class+member+cannot+have+the+%27const%27+keyword.))