# how to use const keyword inside class Typescirpt/angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use `const maxOverviewTextLength:number = 20;` inside my class. But my ide vscode gives error `A class member cannot have the const keyword`.

How can I use const inside class.
Plz help.

```
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit{

movieName:string = "";

movieSearchActive:boolean = true;

popularMovieData:Array<any> = [];

const maxOverviewTextLength:number = 20;

constructor(private _movieListService:MovielistsService){

}
}
```

Comment: Can you try declaring it as private if you are going to use it inside class only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [public static const in typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991968/public-static-const-in-typescript)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that a class member cannot have the `const` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `const` as all class instances are mutable in JS. However, you can use `readonly` to let TypeScript hint errors.

---

More on `readonly`: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/readonly