# Nested class in TypeScript throwing error

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, namespaces

I was following instructions in the [official TypeScript handbook under the section "Merging Namespaces with Classes"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) for how to get nested classes. But it looks like if I try to add a function declaration of any type in the child class definition I get the TS error

> "An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context"

I don't know what this means or why I'm getting this when I'm following the example exactly as far as I can tell.

```
export class Schedule {
    // ...
}

export declare namespace Schedule {
    export class MaxGracePeriod {
        // Static, read-only constants in TypeScript (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22993349/1504964)
        public static get Hourly(): number { return 12; }
        public static get Daily(): number { return 12; }
        public static get Weekly(): number { return 12; }
        public static get Monthly(): number { return 24; }
        public static get Yearly(): number { return 24; }       
        //                ~~~~~~ => "An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context"
    }

    export enum DaysOfWeek {
        Sunday = 0,
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 5,
        Saturday = 6,
    }
}
```

I get the red squiggle and error on the `Hourly()`, `Daily()`, etc. definitions.

Comment: Hint: if you never use the constructor of your class, and it does not have any methods besides static ones, you should not be using `class` syntax at all.

Comment: @Bergi what should I use instead? `interface`?

Comment: A simple object literal. For typing? Yes, probably an interface.

Comment: @Bergi Hmm it gives me a bunch of errors with my method declarations if I change it to `interface`...

Comment: @Bergi How would I declare it as a simple object literal?

Comment: `export const MaxGracePeriod = { Hourly: 12, …}` seems to be [the preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176871/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `declare` from the namespace definition. You don't need that.

```
export class Schedule {
    // ...
}

export namespace Schedule {
    export class MaxGracePeriod {
        public static get Hourly(): number { return 12; }
        public static get Daily(): number { return 12; }
        public static get Weekly(): number { return 12; }
        public static get Monthly(): number { return 24; }
        public static get Yearly(): number { return 24; }       
    }

    export enum DaysOfWeek {
        Sunday = 0,
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 5,
        Saturday = 6,
    }
}
```